# Converting the LINQ to SQl stored procedure

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to convert this linq query to sql stored procedure.

```
var result =
                    from employee in employees.
                        Where
                        (
                            f => bool.Parse(f.Field<string>("isActive"))
                        )

                    from department in departments.
                Where
                (
                    d =>
                        int.Parse(d.Field<string>("empid")) ==
                            int.Parse(employee.Field<string>("empid"))
                ).
                DefaultIfEmpty()

                    from student in students.
                    Where
                    (
                        b =>
                            int.Parse(b.Field<string>("empid")) ==
                                int.Parse((string)employee.Field<string>("empid"))
                    ).
                    DefaultIfEmpty()

                    group new { employee = employee, department = department, student = student } by
                    new
                    {

                        emp_name = employee.Field<string>("empname"),
                        has_benefits =
                            bool.Parse
                            (

                                department == null ?
                                employee.Field<string>("benefits") :
                                department.Field<string>("benefits")
                            ),

                        dept_name =
                            department == null ?
                            string.Empty :
                            department.Field<string>("deptname") as string,
                    }
                        into grp
                    select
                        new
                        {
                            name = grp.Key.emp_name,
                            has_benefits = grp.Key.has_benefits,
                            dept_name = grp.Key.dept_name,
                            local =
                                grp.Any
                                (
                                    entry =>
                                        entry.student != null &&
                                        entry.student.Field<string>("code").Equals("local", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                ),

                        };
```

I am not sure how the select statement should look like. I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM employee e
JOIN department d ON e.empid = d.empid 
JOIN student s ON s.empid = e.empid
WHERE e.isActive = true
GROUP BY 
emp_name, 
CASE( WHEN d == null THEN e.benefits ELSE d.benefits) as has_benefits 
CASE( WHEN d == null THEN '' ELSE d.deptname) as dept_name
```

I am not sure on how the group by should be converted. 
I tried this in the proc but its not giving me the same result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and stored procedure syntax is completely vendor specific) Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you shared your tables layouts or designs. Try the below query, I did not test it though.

```
    SELECT 
        empname,
        deptname,
        CASE WHEN deptname IS NULL THEN E.benefits ELSE D.benefits END AS has_benefits,
        CASE WHEN S.code = S.local THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [local]
    FROM employees AS E
    LEFT JOIN departments AS D ON E.empid = D.empid
    LEFT JOIN students AS S ON E.empid = E.empid
    WHERE E.isActive = 1
    GROUP BY
    empname,
    deptname,
    has_benefits,
    [local]
```